# how to add padding/similar effect to html border

Tags: html, css

I have this line

```
<div class="fixedwidthDiv HRSeparator"></div>
```

throughout the html code I have inherited.
It separates paragraphs of text. 
**What I want is to add a padding of 15px on left and right to this horizontal line**, since I use bootstrap `col-md-12` class also adds this and I have

```
<div class="fixedwidthDiv col-md-12">
```

also at multiple places in my html. So I want to align the text starting position and the horizontal line.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ne5GE/1/

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to align text below the element with the horizontal line wrap everything in a padded container.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="fixedwidthDiv HRSeparator"></div>
    <p>This is some text that will align with the HRSeparator</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    margin: 0px 15px;
}
.HRSeparator {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
.fixedwidthDiv {
   overflow: hidden;
   max-width: 900px;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ne5GE/2/